# Why do you need basic or digest authentication in Django?

Tags: django, apache, authentication

I am struggling to set up for authentication with apache and mod wsgi in Django.

I have a big question mark. It is fundamental question for me before beginning to use basic or digest authentication in apache really.

Why do you need basic or digest authentication in Django in the first place? Django has own authentication system. You can manage permissions with user and permission itself in Django.

I think there is a clear case that you need this apache authentication. I don't think people put effort to explains how to set up for using apache authentication with mod wsgi in Django manual if you don't need it at all.

[In Django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/),

> for example, you could:
>
> 1.Serve static/media files directly from Apache only to authenticated users.
>
> 2.Authenticate access to a Subversion repository against Django users with a certain permission.
>
> 3.Allow certain users to connect to a WebDAV share created with mod_dav.

Even after reading this setence and manual repeatly, I can't come up with some situation which need to select using apache authentication for the best option.

why do you need to use apache authentication in Django or in Which special situation do you need it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. If you don't think you need Apache auth, then don't use it: I certainly never have. What is your question?

Comment: I didn't think apache authentication is not useless even if you use Django own authentication system. So I expect that there would be a case or situation when using apache authentication would be better or compensate some weak part of django authentication system or something else. So I wanted to ask to much more experienced developer if they find some scenario apache authentication is useful with Django system. Can you understand my intention for this question? I hope you explain well enough!

Answer (score 0):

Both `apache` and `django` authentication are different. First one is web server level and next is application level.

One thing, there will be some urls accessible both login and without login.This type of auth cannot be set in `apache`(from my knowledge).You can do it in inside django.

Comment: perhaps, Can you give me more examples in detail, which cases apache authentication could be useful with Django application? My one idea was like this. For example, you do validation check in frontend with javascripts first(like check if you write same passwords when you register new id) and send validated data to backend and backend could check validation again. So I thought using apache authentication is kind of like that, you know like putting one more gate to pass through for more security access. That was just my assumption and wanted to hear from well experienced developers.